# Backing up Home Directory with Filevault 2

Tags: mac, macos, osx-lion

So with the new filevault architecture with OS X Lion, I was wondering if there's any easy way to back up an encrypted home folder. Previous to 10.7, it was quite easy; I could login as my backup user and simply drag the .sparseimage of my home folder right onto my external hard drive. But what concerns me now is that Filevault is encrypting the entire hard drive which unfortunately I can't handle on my external. Has anyone else battled this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timemachine does exactly what you want, have you tried that? Granted, by default it backups everything (which is not necessarily a bad idea), but you can disable that on a per-directory basis.

Comment: The backups are unencrypted, right?

Comment: They can be, but you can also encrypt external volumes since OS X Lion.

Answer (score 0):

For use with SuperDuper! I created an encrypted sparse bundle image (simply via Disk Utility) on my NAS. Works like a charm.